# get row by partition key on aws dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to return a a row with id (partition key)

```
  var db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  const id = "123";
  var queryParams = {
    TableName: "students",
    IndexName: "id",
    KeyConditionExpression: "id = :id",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":id": id,
    },
  };

  const query = db.query(queryParams).promise();
```

but is throwing this error:

```
ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value 'id' at 'indexName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 3
```

isn't partition key enough to get a record? I'm confused partition key is not the same as index name?

I also tried with

```
  var db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  var queryParams = {
    TableName: "students",
    Key: {
      id: "123",
    },
  };

  const query = db.get(queryParams).promise();
```

and it doesn't return anything

Comment: Your newly-added code that calls `get` works just fine on a table with an item whose partition key, named `id`, has string value "123". How are you determining that the code doesn't return anything?

Comment: Also, you asked "I'm confused partition key is not the same as index name?" No, they're not the same (in any database). One is a column (or attribute) name while the other is an (arbitrary) index name. An index name is analogous to a table name (not a column name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually have an index named `id`. You don't need to provide an index when querying on the partition key. Simply remove this line:

```
IndexName: "id",
```

Also, note that both table and index names must be 3-255 characters in length (inclusive), which explains the error message that you see.

The following code (both query and get) works fine for me:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const ID = "123";
const TABLE_NAME = "students";

const getParams = {
  TableName: TABLE_NAME,
  Key: {
    id: ID,
  },
};

const queryParams = {
  TableName: TABLE_NAME,
  KeyConditionExpression: "id = :id",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":id": ID,
  },
};

(async () => {
  const rc1 = await db.get(getParams).promise();
  console.log('get rc:', rc1);

  const rc2 = await db.query(queryParams).promise();
  console.log('query rc:', rc2);
})();
```

Comment: interesting that you don't get a warning/error while creating a table. `id` is pretty standard.

Comment: Get a warning/error for what? You can't create an index named `id`. Attempting to do so will fail (with "Index names must include between 3 and 255 characters ..."). Are you mixing up a column/attribute name (which can be `id`) with index name (which cannot be `id`)?

Comment: I want to get the record with id 123.

Comment: Did you do what I suggested? Did it fail? If so, how?

Comment: ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeValues can only be specified when using expressions: FilterExpression is null

Comment: I added working code. Does it work for you?